# UILabel in UITableViewCell not updating on NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nstimer

In viewDidAppear method, I initialised an NSTimer. (self.dayView is initialised in the loadView-method).

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(reloadTableView)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
}

- (void)reloadTableView {
    [self.dayView.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And my cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cell for row at indexpath called");
    MatchEventCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    MatchEvent *event = [self getMatchEventAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                                   fromDate:[NSDate date]
                                                     toDate:event.startDate
                                                    options:0];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d", [dateComponents hour], [dateComponents minute], [dateComponents second]];
    NSLog(@"TEXT = %@", cell.textLabel.text);

    return cell;
}
```

As I test this timer in the Simulator, the label in my cell is not updated.
When i look at the NSLog, I see that "TEXT = ..." the new value that is set to the textLabel.

Why is my label not visually updated, although the NSLog shows that the textLabel has a new text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you make changes to the underlying data source, you need to update the table view manual. `UITableView's reloadData` method is the quick and **inefficient** way to do it. **The correct way is:**

```
NSArray *cells = [myTableView visibleCells];
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (UITableViewCell *cell in cells) {
    [indexPaths addObject:[myTableView indexPathForCell:cell]];
}
[myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:NO];
[indexPaths release];
```

The rest of the rows that are not visible will be updated once you scroll and they appear.

Let us know if this works, otherwise could be a thread problem...

Comment: doesn't work for me.. I already tried adding a "performSelectorOnMainThread"-method, but still nothing seems to be updated.. strange thing is that the NSLog tells the label is updated, but nothing visually changed.

Comment: As I can see in your code, the NSLog doesn't print the same information that the cell text label. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Nope.. I changed this example for a default understanding... I edited the question to make it right!

Comment: Are those cells that you are trying to refresh visible?

Comment: Try this then in your reload table view method after the reload data, [self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];

Comment: Then, try to do a better use of the UITableCell (MatchEventCell in your case), in your code you are not using it properly and that could be a problem too. You should initialize and rehuse the UITableCell. More information in: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Apparently, stuff starts working now... There was a little issue when getting the right data which resulted in a threading issue... now everything works fine, so thanks for helping me out!
Concerning the use of UITableViewCell, my app only supports iOS 7, so when using [self.tableView registerClass ...] in loadView, it is not necessary to initialise the UITableViewCell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath-method.

Comment: can you close this question ? I'm not entitled to do so :)

Comment: I'm just checking info about how to close the question and I cannot neither.. The only way is you just accepting the answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com